# The redirected output is not showing in the text box

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

I am new to visual studio. I want to write a Windows Form Application that opens "cmd.exe" and the user can enter the command in a textbox. The output message from cmd should be redirected to another textbox. For some reason, the output message is not showing up at the textbox

I have tried googling the answers and none of them seems to work for me. Really appreciated if someone can help me identify the issue

```
        public cmd_helper()
        {
            //Initialize
            InitializeComponent();
            Load_Cmd_String();
            updata_box();
        }

        private void Start_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
            {
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                WorkingDirectory = @"C:\",
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Verb = "runas"

            };

            // event handlers for output & error
            myProcess.OutputDataReceived += myProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += myProcess_ErrorDataReceived;

            // start process
            myProcess.Start();
            cmd_output_text.AppendText("cmd running...\n");
        }

        private void Close_buttom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myProcess.Close();
            cmd_output_text.AppendText("cmd closed...\n");
        }

        private void myProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, 
             DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Process myProcess = sender as Process;
            if (myProcess == null)
                return;
            cmd_output_text.AppendText(e.Data);
        }

        private void myProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, 
             DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Process myProcess = sender as Process;
            if (myProcess == null)
                return;
            cmd_output_text.AppendText(e.Data);
        }

        private void Send_cmd_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         myProcess.StandardInput.Write(command[name.IndexOf(command_box.Text)] + myProcess.StandardInput.NewLine);
        }
```

Note: 
   I have two buttons which are "start" and "stop" which will open and close the cmd.exe.
  The user should be to type something like: dir, cd to some dir, cd to another dir

Comment: Hmm, not sure, but it could be that you need to execute `cmd_output_text.AppendText` on the UI thead (the thread the control has been created in). Something like `cmd_output_text.Invoke( () => { cmd_output_text.AppendText(...); } );` (Again, i am not sure and i might be barking up the wrong tree here...)

Comment: Ah, i must have been blind. I overlooked the bull in the china shop... You didn't enable redirection of the standard output and error streams/channels, and you also didn't prime your Process object for the usage of the OutputDataReceived/ErrorDataReceived events. Look at the code sample in the documentation for either the OutputDataReceived ErrorDataReceived event and read the Remarks section attentively and carefully..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
private void myProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Process myProcess = sender as Process;
    if (myProcess == null)
        return;
    cmd_output_text.Invoke(new Action (delegate { cmd_output_text.AppendText("\n"+e.Data); }));
}
```

Also u need to add this line "myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();" to your code

```
private void Start_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError=true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\",
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Verb = "runas"

        };

        // event handlers for output & error
        myProcess.OutputDataReceived += myProcess_OutputDataReceived;
        myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += myProcess_ErrorDataReceived;

        // start process
        myProcess.Start();
        **myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();**
        cmd_output_text.AppendText("cmd running...\n");
    }
```

Hope its help u!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
{
      var p = new Process();  
      p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  
      p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;  
      p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";  
      p.Start();  

      // To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then wait.  
      string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();  
      p.WaitForExit();

      Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: Note the the code in the question is a WinForms application. Using `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` with `p.WaitForExit()` is not really a good choice in such a scenario.